# Как работает выражение +(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]])

Tags: javascript

Недавно столкнулся с очень странным выражением - `+(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]])`. Странно то, что оно ровно 10.

```js
console.log(+(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]))
```

Не смог разобраться как оно работает. Как вообще выражение из массивов и плюсов может быть ровно 10?

Comment: выражение из массивов и плюсов может быть чем угодно, в том числе и строкой, которую можно передать, например в `eval`, либо добавив круглые скобки произвести непосредственный вызов

Comment: Там используется унарный оператор `+` и такой же обыкновенный оператор `+` для арифметических варыжений.

Comment: @ΝNL993 уже пояснили :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для того, чтобы разобраться как все работает, достаточно расставить скобочки и вычислить все выражения по порядку:

```
+(++([[]][(+[])])+[(+[])])
```

Отформатируем

```
+ ( // 5
  ++ ( // 3
    [[]][ // 2
      +[] // 1
    ]
  )
  + [ // 4
    +[] // 1 
  ]
)
```

Рассмотрим по шагам:

1. `+[]` - унарный `+` переводит операнд в число. Пустой массив приводится к пустой строке, после этого пустая строка переводится в число `0`.

   ```
   + ( // 5
     ++ ( // 3
       [[]][ // 2
         0
       ]
     )
     + [ // 4
       0
     ]
   )
   ```
2. `[[]][0]` - получение элемента массива по индексу. В данном случае вернется `[]` - нулевой элемент из `[[]]`

   ```
   + ( // 5
     ++ ( // 3
       []
     )
     + [ // 4
       0
     ]
   )
   ```
3. `++ ([])` - данный шаг выполняется вместе со вторым, `[]` одновременно приводится к `0` и увеличивается на `1`.

   ```
   + ( // 5
     1
     + [ // 4
       0
     ]
   )
   ```
4. `1 + [0]` - складываются разнородные операнды, второй приводится к `'0'` что равносильно складыванию числа и  строки `1 + '0'`, результат `'10'`

   ```
   + ( // 5
     '10'
   )
   ```
5. `+'10'` - применение унарного плюса к строке, приводит ее к числу. Результат - 10

Comment: При чём если выполнить ++[] отдельно, будет ошибка

Comment: @T0xee.n17, поэтому сделал уточнение, что третий шаг работает в связке со вторым. Суть в передаче оператору именно выражения, а не литерала